# Call soap web service using HttpWebRequest in Windows Store Apps

Tags: web-services, windows-store-apps, httpwebrequest, soap-client

Let me clear one thing that i don't wanna use "Add Service Reference" method. I want to call a soap service using HttpWebRequest in windows store app. I have working soap web service given by my client. I only have access to the web service but not source code. I have searched the internet but couldn't find solution for Windows store app.

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid using *Add Service Reference*? Even so, I strongly discourage you from using `HttpWebRequest` directly as you will lose all the benefits of having the SOAP protocol already implemented.

You can use [`ChannelFactory<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), though; even from a Windows Store app:

- First create the interface from the web service WSDL using `svcutil.exe`:

  ```
  svcutil /serviceContract http://localhost:61547/Service1.svc?wsdl
  ```
- Include the generated code file in your Windows Store project.
- Create the channel and call a method on it from your code:

  ```
  var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61547/Service1.svc");
  var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint);
  var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
  var result = channel.GetData(3);
  ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
  ```

I tried it out with a sample web service and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did the same but when I included generated to the project, it gave me bunch of errors. Such as

 'The type or namespace name 'SerializableAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

Comment: @SaadAnees In this case you'll need to include more information in your question to get help, such as WSDL of your web service, the errors that you got, etc.

Comment: for this i have to make another question with relevant information but my real problem is that i have to make app for Windows Phone 8.1 RT and Windows Store app so there is no way to add service reference of soap service to windows phone 8.1 RT. So i was hoping to do something that work on both platform. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @SaadAnees You didn't mention Windows Phone before. There is no SOAP client support in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT and you don't want to implement it yourself unless your web service is really really simple. I suggest you either use Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight SDK which includes the required APIs or switch to a REST based web service, if that's an option.

Comment: Are you sure? because I can't use silverlight. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @SaadAnees I'm pretty sure. [Here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/253374-missing-platform-apis/suggestions/6092460-system-servicemodel-wcf-in-windows-phone-8-1-for) you can vote for this missing feature. Maybe there's a third party library available that I don't know of.